# Can I force Eureka registrations to use an ip address instead of a hostname?

Tags: spring-cloud

I have a standalone, embedded Eureka server powered by Spring Boot 1.2.0.RELEASE and Spring Cloud 1.0.0.RC1. I see services properly registering themselves in the dashboard, which is great.  The status links are using the host name of the box they are running on.  Unfortunately, we are using virtual machines and they don't register themselves in DNS, which means that the links are unresolvable.  I started looking through the code but was unable to find a way to force the links to use the host's ip address instead.  Having a broken dashboard is not the end of the world but I am afraid that once we start using Ribbon or Feign to contact services, those URLs will also use the host name and be unresolvable. Maybe what I am really asking is there a way to force the clients to register with an ip address instead of a host name? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

set `eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true` as documented [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/a7398842078319dcaa353a708c12bb7b9fa85a4e/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-netflix.adoc#prefer-ip-address)

Comment: Could you provide some reference to this setting? Code-only answer is discouraged since it might confuse not only OP, but also future viewers.

Comment: Thank you for the setting.  Adding `eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true` to the `application.properties` of my Eureka clients did the trick -- sort of.  I now see something similar to [UP (1) - 127.0.1.1](http://127.0.1.1:34965/info) in the Eureka dashboard.  I found the code where they are obtaining host information (EurekaInstanceConfigBean) and it appears to be only looking at localhost.  I guess I'll have to see about opening a ticket to see if anybody has ideas on a solution.

Comment: The loopback address issue appears to have been caused by a misconfiguration in the `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: [Spring Cloud Reference Documentation prefer_ip_address](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#_prefer_ip_address)

Comment: I tested in the version 2.16,  the option doesn't work.

Comment: There is no version 2.16